# Laravel 5.4: Change DB according to sub domain in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a SAAS application with a single laravel installation and multi tenant database. 
So i have a main DB that is connected to laravel by default. the client can access the application through their sub-domain like: client1.example.com and client2.example.com

I am saving all info fo the client like domain and db name in the main db.

How can change the DB according to the subdomain

I tried with the following Code

in `routes/web.php`

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function($account) {
        // This will return {account}, which you can pass along to what you'd like
        return $account;
    });

});
```

in `app/Providers\RouteServiceProvieder.php`

```
 public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        parent::boot($router);

        $router->bind('domain', function ($value) {
            //$hst=$request->getHost();
            $domain= Customer::where('sub_domain',$value)->first();
            if ($domain) {
                return $domain;
            }
            throw new Exception('error message');
        });

    }
```

Then i have created a ServiceProvider `ConfigServiceProvider`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class ConfigServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $customer=$request->route('domain');
        //$customer = Request::route('domain');  // there are multiple ways of doing this
        //$customer = $request->route()->domain;
        config([
            'database.mysql.database' => $customer->customer_database,  //this is because I have same username and password for all the databases. If you have different username and passwords set them too.
        ]);
        DB::reconnect(); // this will help in reconnecting the database if the connection is already established. and import the DB facade.
    }
}
```

But the code is not working?

The Error i am getting is

```
FatalThrowableError in ConfigServiceProvider.php line 25:
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider::register(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\main\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php on line 568 and exactly 1 expected
```

I am using Laravel 5.4. Can any one guide me how to do it correctly?

Comment: do you have seperate codebase for each sub domain?

Comment: @SameerShaikh no i am using same code for all databases. All models and controllers are common

Comment: what are the names of databases

Answer (score 4):

well there are some issues here:

First the register() method of a service provider should not accept a Request instance as argument. Its better to write it like that:

```
public function register()
```

Second, dont use config() in the register() method, from the laravel docs:

> within the register method, you should only bind things into the
>   service container. You should never attempt to register any event
>   listeners, routes, or any other piece of functionality within the
>   register method. Otherwise, you may accidentally use a service that is
>   provided by a service provider which has not loaded yet.

IMHO I would use a middleware to change the database configuration like you tried in a service provider, i.e:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{        
    $customer=$request->route('domain');
    if($customer)
    {
        config(['database.mysql.database' => $customer->customer_database]);
        DB::reconnect();
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

If you take care of loading the middleware in the right place (look in app/Http/Kernel.php) you will have database changed before any query.

Comment: i tried with that also it didn't work. i am already using some route groups in web.php. Can you please tell me what will be the route group to call middleware in web.php?

Comment: check if $customer is set and if yes change connection, i update code.

Comment: Ok, So i have used this in my web.php file
`Route::group([ 'domain' => '{account}', 'middleware'=>'subdomain_setup' ], function(){});`

Also i have used a model to get db details after request->route('domain')
but still no luck

Comment: have you put your middlweare in Kernel.php?

Comment: Yes i did in protected $routeMiddleware

Comment: try to use it as $middlewareGroups, put it in last position under 'web' key. As written above it change database config only if route('domain') is set.

Comment: IMHO middleware is the way to go, probably you have others issues

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is to create 2 `.env` files, one for each subdomain e.g. `.env.domain1` and `.env.domain2`

Then in your app service provider:

```
public function boot() {      //Use boot for this  
    $fn = ".env.".$this->app->request->route('domain');
    $dotenv = new \Dotenv\Dotenv(self::basePath(), $fn);
    try {
        $dotenv->overload();
    } catch (\Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
       //Nothing to overload with
    }
}
```

This makes your sub-domains behave like different environments which does look like what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

to

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

You can not use Facades for dependency/method injection. Hope it helps